# VBA If statement don't work sometimes

Tags: vba, if-statement

I've made a very long script to reoganize an excel file. So I'm working with several if and they work all fine. I'm trying to undestand what's wrong with theese 2 part of code:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "cass", 1) Then
    Cells(i, 135).Value = Cells(i, 135).Value & "/cassetti.jpg::cassetti inox;;/cassetti2.jpg::cassetti inox;;"
End If
```

In the Cells 5 I've Words like "Cassetti" or "Cassettiera"  Now with word "cass" it write on the cell, only sometimes. This thing is driving me crazy from 2 days.. You see something that I don't see?

Edit:
This is a more big part of my code:

```
Cells(1, 135) = "media_gallery"
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "tavol", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "lav", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "vasc", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_tav
End If

If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "armadiat", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_tav_arm
End If
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "armadio", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_arm
End If
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "arm", 1) And InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "cass", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_cass_arm
End If
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "caldo", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_caldo
End If
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "labirinto", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_asp
End If
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "lavatoio", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "vasco", 1) Then
Cells(i, 135).Value = img_lav
End If
If (InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "lavat", 1) Or InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "vasco", 1)) Then
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "armad", 1) Then
       Cells(i, 135).Value = img_lav_arm
End If
End If
If InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "pens", 1) And InStr(1, Cells(i, 5), "scorr", 1) Then
 Cells(i, 135).Value = img_pensile
End If
If Cells(i, 5).Value Like "*cass*" Then
 Cells(i, 135).Value = Cells(i, 135).Value & "/cassetti.jpg::cassetti inox;;/cassetti2.jpg::cassetti     inox;;"
End If
```

And theese are variable declared at the begin of the script:

```
img_tav = "/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;"
img_tav_arm = "/anta.jpg::anta inox scorrevole;;/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio    inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;/saldatura2.jpg::saldatura;;/top-raggiato.jpg::Top raggiato  opzionale;;/fianchi.jpg::fianchi inox lisci;;"
img_arm = "/anta.jpg::anta inox scorrevole;;/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;/saldatura2.jpg::saldatura;;/fianchi.jpg::fianchi inox lisci;;"
img_cass = "/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;/saldatura2.jpg::saldatura;;/top-raggiato.jpg::Top raggiato opzionale;;"
img_cass_arm = "/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;/saldatura2.jpg::saldatura;;/top-raggiato.jpg::Top raggiato opzionale;;/fianchi.jpg::fianchi inox lisci;;"
img_caldo = "/caldo.jpg::tavolo caldo;;/anta.jpg::anta inox scorrevole;;/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;/saldatura2.jpg::saldatura;;/top-raggiato.jpg::Top raggiato opzionale;;/fianchi.jpg::fianchi inox lisci;;"
img_asp = "/labirinto.jpg::filtri a labirinto;;"
img_lav = "/troppo-pieno.jpg::Troppo Pieno;;"
img_lav_arm = "/troppo-pieno.jpg::Troppo Pieno;;/anta.jpg::anta inox scorrevole;;/piede.jpg::piede in acciaio inox;;/saldatura.jpg::saldatura;;/saldatura2.jpg::saldatura;;/top-raggiato.jpg::Top raggiato opzionale;;/fianchi.jpg::fianchi inox lisci;;"
img_pensile = "/guide-pensili.jpg::Guide Anti Sporco;;/anta.jpg::anta inox scorrevole;;"
```

All of them are working fine but not the last If..

Comment: Uppercase *C* and lowercase *c* are not the same, and you're testing only for lowercase *c*. *cass* matches because the *c* is lowercase; *Cassetti* does not because the *C* is UPPERCASE.

Comment: I've other if working even If I don't use uppercase

Comment: Show the rest of your code. ..

Comment: The code is very long, About 300 lines or more... I don't succed to format it here.. i try to copy a part of it

Answer (score 0):

Use `Option Compare Text` at the top of the module where this code is placed, or, cast your strings to consistent case, e.g.:

```
Dim myString as Variant
myString = LCase(Cstr(Cells(1,5).value))
If InStr(1, myString, "cass", 1) Then
    Cells(i, 135).Value = Cells(i, 135).Value & "/cassetti.jpg::cassetti inox;;/cassetti2.jpg::cassetti inox;;"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Like`:

```
If myString Like "cass*" Then
```

It's more readable, much faster and case insensitive

Comment: even with like it's the same... And I've other if with the same system and they are working even if I have Uppercase in the searched words